# How to run a 3rd party app in 'Kiosk Mode'

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to launch a 3rd party app in 'Kiosk Mode' i.e. to disable the System Bars, Home button, Back button etc while the app is running?

I'm writing an app from which the user can launch Skype to make a video call.

I want both my app and Skype to run in Kiosk Mode.

I have managed to get my app running in Kiosk Mode, but I can't work out how to control the system buttons when Skype is running.

Within my app, I achieve it by doing things like setting my app as the Home app, overriding 'OnWindowFocusChange' etc. There are a lot of articles on the web about how to do this kind of thing, but they all seem to be based on the assumption it's your own app you want to 'kiosk'

For what it's worth, I launch Skype with:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("skype:echo123?call&video=true");
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

I know it's possible to kiosk external applications because [SureLock](http://www.42gears.com/surelock) does it.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Damian.

Comment: Post a demonstration of the what you're talking about and also you're link is dead.

Comment: @JoxTraex - thanks, I've fixed the link. Not sure what I can demonstrate .. in SureLock, you can set it up so that it launches a particular app (e.g. Skype) on boot up and disables all the system buttons. To demo this would just be a screen-shot of Skype?

Comment: There's a lot to locking down Android properly; you'll need to figure out a way to always keep the app on top without Android killing it. You'll need to keep any of the system UI's out, such as task switcher, home launcher, system dialogs, and notifications. Attempts to power down the Android system need to be dealt with such that the app comes back when android starts again. You may want to try an off-the-shelf solution. In addition to the product you mentioned, [KioWare Kiosk Software for Android](http://www.kioware.com) and Site Kiosk are other options. (full disclosure: I work for KioWare)

Comment: Hi @DamianHelme, may I ask for source of this kiosk mode? I really don't know what to do and I need it very badly. :(